# How to make a revers PTR in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to make a PTR record, but having some struggles. This is the code used for AAAA record, which works:

```
resource "dns_aaaa_record_set" "app-stage-dns" {
  count     = length(var.datacenter)
  zone      = format("%s.", var.dns_zone)
  name      = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.mydomain"
  addresses = [replace(openstack_compute_instance_v2.app-stage[count.index].access_ip_v6, "/\\[|\\]/", "")]
  ttl       = 300
}
```

I got some variables set:

```
dns_zone   = "mydomain.com"
dns_ptr_zone = "0.c.0.0.a.a.a.a.ip6.arpa"
```

Example of ipaddress:

- aaaa:c0:4f0:2300:f816:3eff:fe52:7a19

And the end result should be like this:

- 9.1.a.7.2.5.e.f.f.f.e.3.6.1.8.f.0.0.3.2.0.f.4.0.0.c.0.0.a.a.a.a.ip6.arpa

Here is the code for PTR record:

```
resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr" {
  count = length(var.datacenter)
  zone  = format("%s.", var.dns_ptr_zone)
  ptr   = "app-stage-[count.index].mydomain.com."
  name  = strrev(tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses)[0])
  ttl   = 300
}
```

But with this i get:

- 91a7:25ef:ffe3:618f:0032:0f4:0c:20a2.0.c.0.0.a.a.a.a.ip6.arpa.

Comment: So you want/need to do a bit more post-processing of your `AAAA` address if I understand correctly? Replacing `:` and then splitting and joining would do the trick: `join(".", split("", strrev(replace("aaaa:c0:4f0:2300:f816:3eff:fe52:7a19", ":", ""))))` produces `"9.1.a.7.2.5.e.f.f.f.e.3.6.1.8.f.0.0.3.2.0.f.4.0.c.a.a.a.a"`.

Answer (score 0):

Code that solves this issue:

```
resource "dns_ptr_record" "dns-ptr-aaaa" {
  for_each = var.nodes
  zone  = format("%s.", var.dns_ptr_zone)
  ptr   = "${each.value}-${each.key}.${var.domain}."
  name  = strrev(join(".", [for s in split(":", replace(tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.dns-aaaa[each.key].addresses)[0], "aaaa:c0:", "")): join(".", regex("(.)(.)(.)(.)$", "000${s}"))]))
  ttl   = 300
}
```